# Python Pygame Не отображаются кадры и спрайты при передвижении игрока в право или в лево

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

Решил создать простую игру по видео-уроку с ютуба и столкнулся с проблемой: При зажатии клавиш вправо или в лево не отображаются кадры передвижения игрока а только кадр от начала пути и кадр конец пути.
Мой код:

```
import pygame
from turtle import width as t_width

pygame.init()
win =  pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes")
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('right_1.png'), pygame.image.load('right_2.png'), pygame.image.load('right_3.png'), pygame.image.load('right_4.png'), pygame.image.load('right_5.png'), pygame.image.load('right_6.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('left_1.png'), pygame.image.load('left_2.png'), pygame.image.load('left_3.png'), pygame.image.load('left_4.png'), pygame.image.load('left_5.png'), pygame.image.load('left_6.png')]

bg = pygame.image.load('bg.png')
playerStand = pygame.image.load('player.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50
y = 249
width = 40
height = 60
speed = 10

isJump = False
JumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
animCount = 0

def drawWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))


    if animCount + 1 >=30:
        animCount = 0
    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x, y,))
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))
        pygame.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 249 and x > 375:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 440 - width - 5 and x > 380 and x < 410:
        y += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 10:
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - 10:
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        animCount = 0

    if not(isJump):

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    else:
        if JumpCount >= -10:
            if JumpCount < 0:
                y += (JumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (JumpCount ** 2) / 2
            JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            JumpCount = 10




    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False
    drawWindow()
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что значение переменной animCount не изменяется. все что у тебя происходит с этой переменной, это её объявление

```
animCount = 0
```

далее она используется в условии

```
if animCount + 1 >=30:
    animCount = 0
```

и в конце ты делишь по сути статичное число на цело на 5

```
win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
```

animCount переводится как счетчик анимации. у тебя есть массив

```
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('right_1.png'), pygame.image.load('right_2.png'), pygame.image.load('right_3.png'), pygame.image.load('right_4.png'), pygame.image.load('right_5.png'), pygame.image.load('right_6.png')]
```

и animCount подразумевает, что ты будешь перебирать индексы(порядковые номера элементов в списке) массива, каждое мгновение рисуя новую картинку просто увеличивая её значение на единицу и когда значение превысит количество картинок, приравнять к нулю, чтобы начать все по новой

```
animCount += 1
```

Могу предложить тебе две вещи, если тебе нравится создавать игры и ты готов учиться(и страдать):

1. книга "Учим пайтон делая крутые игры" Эл Свейгарт. не такие уж они и крутые, но в питоне помогут освоиться.
2. никогда не сдавайся

Comment: спасибо Большое Андрей Таков